# Android application name not correct in apps, but is correct in Application Manager

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am still learning Android app development. I have an app that I am developing in Android Studio. In my phones application manager, the name of the app is correct. In my apps, it shows Main Menu for the app name. I have tried clearing cache, uninstalling and re-installing. I have checked the Android Manifest. Everything looks correct.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxxx" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MultipleChoice"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_multiple_choice" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Ultra Math</string>

    <string name="RightText">Right</string>
    <string name="option1">1st Option</string>
    <string name="option2">2nd Option</string>
    <string name="LeftText">Left</string>
    <string name="OperatorText">+</string>
    <string name="StartButton">Start</string>
    <string name="TimeLeft">Time Left: 60</string>
    <string name="btn0">0</string>
    <string name="btn1">1</string>
    <string name="btn2">2</string>
    <string name="btn3">3</string>
    <string name="btn4">4</string>
    <string name="btn5">5</string>
    <string name="btn6">6</string>
    <string name="btn7">7</string>
    <string name="btn8">8</string>
    <string name="btn9">9</string>
    <string name="btnEnter">Enter</string>
    <string name="btnNegative">-</string>
    <string name="title_activity_menu">Ultra Math</string>

    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main_menu">Main Menu</string>
    <string name="btnTypeAnswers">Type Answers</string>
    <string name="Zero">0</string>
    <string name="two">2</string>
    <string name="title_activity_multiple_choice">Multiple Choice</string>
    <string name="btnMultipleChoice">Multiple Choice</string>
</resources>
```

Is there any place else that I can look, or anything else that I can try?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes its name from the title of the launcher activity. so you need to change the string at title_activity_main_menu

or set it like this

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainMenu"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you. That did it, but I have to wait 8 minutes before I can mark this as the answer, lol. But now I have a follow-up question. What is the purpose then of the Label property of the Application tag in the Android Manifest?

Comment: The purpose is to identify the application, such as through the application manager as you said. A single app can have multiple entry points/launcher activities, so the launcher is taking the one for that particular activity. they often refer to the same string but there are situations where you want those values to be different

Comment: I'm sorry. What do you want me to write in a comment?

Comment: Ok, thank you for the thorough explanation. That makes sense.